CLI SAM Deploy Fails on SSL Certificate Verification
I'm getting the SSL validation error below when trying to do a SAM deploy of our Lambda (on Windows 11). We are using PaloAlto GlobalProtect as our VPN. When I disable GlobalPotect, it works just fine.
I have tried using the EXPORT_CA_BUNDLE environment variable, pointing it to the .pem of our self-signed certificate but it doesn't work either. The version of the SAM CLI is 1.111.0.
Error: Unable to upload artifact WorkAssistantApi referenced by CodeUri parameter of WorkAssistantApi resource.
SSL validation failed for https://wrk-asst-val-code-deploy-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/9273d6cd25e71042ef8f346ac8be6074 [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)


Did you use a relative path or an absolute path when you specified the path on this environment variable?

Can you try to update your SAM CLI's version? the latest version of SAM is 1.117+ at the time of this answer's writing. If in case you are using certifi, consider updating the version certifi in your computer by running pip install certifi and add your .pem file in its certificate store. If none works after this, considering calling in your security team haha.

We updated to the latest version of the SAM CLI and the problem went away.
